# Listening and Receiving messages through a port

Tags: messaging

Am creating a lanmessenger in c#. And i have the code to receive and send messages through a port, but I am having a 'minor' confusion regarding how to use them. 
Should I constantly call the function that listens to the port from which incoming messages are to be received in each event?.. If so, then how do i call the function which shall send messages?

Answer (score 2):

Either use the **asynchronous methods** (e.g. [`BeginReceive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive.aspx)), or look at [**threading**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx)...

If you use the asynchronous methods, you won't get bogged down by polling, because you will receive a [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx) when data is received.

If you use threading, you can poll (for example by checking the [`Available`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available.aspx) property of a `TcpClient` in a loop), and it won't prevent the rest of your code from executing, because the polling will be in its own thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was adamant at using synchronous connections but that obviously will make life harder.

Comment: @Avik:  If you don't want to use the asynch stuff, Threading works  (that's usually the approach that I take)